# Python 2.7.12 socket.send with Timer

Tags: python, sockets, timer

i wanna set timer to send data with socket

but error occur like first picture

[in ubuntu 14.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub91X.png)

```
Timer(len(p.pkt)/Router.bandwidth, Router.socket.send, (p.pkt)).start()
```

i wrote 1 argument(p.pkt). but error is 'there is no argument'

how can i set timer to socket.send function?

i use this site for Timer class

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html

Comment: The picture is error message in ubutu 14.04

Comment: Why did you include the error message as a picture instead of copy+paste it into the question? Also, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create enough code so that others can reproduce your problem and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your program to stop for a set amount of time before performing the next step you can use the `time` function.

```
import time
time.sleep(seconds)
```

For example

```
import time
print('Text A')
time.sleep(2)
print('Text B')
```

The program will print 'Text A' wait for 2 seconds then print 'Text B'.

I hope I managed to help.